# Save HTML table to external HTML file from password protected page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I need to pull whole html table from password protected page and save it to external html file.

`<table id="tblControlorStatus" class="dataTable" aria-describedby="" style="">`

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://MYURL")

assert "Page title" in driver.title 

username = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Login1_UserName")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("MYUSER")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$Password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("MYPASS")

driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Login1$LoginButton").click()

driver.find_element_by_link_text("MYLINKTEXT").click()

html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
div=soup.select_one("table#tblControlorStatus")
table=pd.read_html(str(div), header = 0)
print(table[0])
```

This only prints values from the table to terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
table=pd.read_html(str(div), header = 0)
print(table[0])
```

Try something like this

```
html_content = str(div)
html_file = open("output.html", "w")
html_file.write(html_content)
html_file.close()
```

That should write your table to an external file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks....it worked with this little modification:

```
html_file = open('D://output.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
html_file.write(html_content)
html_file.close()'
```